# Windows Admin Center RemoteException: The specified module 'CimCmdlets' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019, sysadmin, windows-admin-center

I'm setting up Windows Admin Center and have successfully added a few servers. However, I'm encountering an issue when connecting to a server, and the error message I'm receiving is:

"RemoteException: The specified module 'CimCmdlets' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory."

I've attempted to resolve this by adding the following to the system PATH, but unfortunately, it hasn't been successful.

*;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules*

Here is the command I used:

```
$key = (Get-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager').OpenSubKey('Environment', $true)
$path = $key.GetValue('PSModulePath','','DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
$path += ';C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules'
$key.SetValue('PSModulePath',$path,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
```

I've confirmed that CimCmdlets is installed on the server. Does anyone have experience with this issue or suggestions on how to resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

*When I logon using the admin account of the server, the  error doesn't occur. Could it be that the user doesn't have enough permissions?*

Comment: What about running it from an admin elevated PowerShell as the account it gives the error, does that work?

Comment: With a admin elevated Powershell it does work.

Comment: Well, there you go. To access that reg path and property/key detail, it must require admin elevation, and especially is setting a value too!